# Handling REST Delete request CPPRESTSDK

Tags: rest, http, listener, cpprest-sdk

I want to handle delete request  on server side by using cpprestsdk. But the problem is the end part of url is string and can contain any value.
ex [http://127.0.0.1/subscriptions/{"it](http://127.0.0.1/subscriptions/%7B%22it) is id in string format"}.
How to create a single listener for that?.

Do I need to create a separate listener for seperate id .Like
one http listener for http://127.0.0.1/subscriptions/1
another http listener for http://127.0.0.1/subscriptions/2

I think this method is ugly.

Comment: Can i create listener in cpprestsdk which is listeneing at

http://127.0.0.1/subscriptions/{userID} and useID can contain any string value.

Answer (score 0):

The request is can be written as `subscriptions/{id}`

```
void handle_delete(http_request request)
{
   // Get the value of the "id" parameter from the URI
    auto id = request.relative_uri().path().substr(15); // 15 is the length at wich id starts
}
```